# override d3js chart xAxis and yAxis font family of sans-serief to cusotmized one

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3js in my application of angular and said it before I am using D3js for chart rendering,However I am trying to override existing behavior appearance of font-family on xAxis and yAxis, it does happen but I can see that is both of them applied one is default and one is part of style.

Here is the snippet, what I would like to do it should have font-family as my customized font not sans-serief

```
<g class="axisY" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end" style="font-family: my-customized-font-family;"><path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M0.5,320.5V0.5"></path>
```

I want my customized font family to applied for x-axis and y-axis not sans-serief.

//Here is the updated code. which produces both inline style of my customized font and default sans-serif provided by d3js

```
 var yAxis = g =>
        g
          .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(0))
          .call(leftOffsetYAxisLabels)
          .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove());

      g.append("g").attr("class", "test") .style("font-family", "my-font").call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Could you share the d3.js code which is producing that element?

Comment: see my above code please

Comment: Please show more code so that we can setup a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The code you are showing wouldn't produce the element you have described above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply these attributes after the call():

g.append("g").attr("class", "test").call(yAxis).attr("font-family", "my-font");

The .call, adds its own g node attributes... as you see in your example, thereby replacing any attributes applied beforehand.

The adding of class attribute does work when applied as you have, prior to the call().